# Meaning of '< >' in perl

Tags: perl

I was looking for a way to read from file in perl , and i find the followng example :

```
open($FH_READ, "data.txt");    
    while ($line = <$FH_READ> )
    {
      ....
    }
```

my question is what '< >' mean in perl ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It reads your file line by line](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators). It's equivalent to writing `while($line = readline(*$FH_READ)) { … }`.

Comment: and in realine function , what is '*' sign in '*$FH_READ' ?

Comment: I think the important message is, that it reads a file _line by line_ ;) If you need to know, it is the [type prefix of a typeglob](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles)

Comment: well , it's good to know something new :) , thank you anyway ^_^

Comment: It's worth noting that `<...>` also serves another function in Perl - it can be used as a shortcut for the `glob` function. `@scripts = <*.pl>` is equivalent to `@scripts = glob('*.pl')`.

Comment: @reinierpost: The example given by the OP reads the file line by line. Sure, it has different behaviour in different contexts, but here it reads a file linewise.

Answer (score 1):

If you see a Perl operator that you don't understand, then it's a good idea to read the [Perl operator documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html). In this case you want the [section on I/O Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I/O-Operators).

> In scalar context, evaluating a filehandle in angle brackets yields
>   the next line from that file (the newline, if any, included), or undef
>   at end-of-file or on error.

Answer (score 0):

You can also read the entire line in by using `<$FH_READ>` in list context:

```
my @lines= <$FH_READ> ;
```